# Objective C - UI Slider Pointer move only from one range value to other

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on UISlider functionality. I have only 4 range values (0, 1, 2, 3). So, I have given minimum value as 0 and maximum as 3. But my slider is not directly switching from 0-1, 1-2, 2-3. It is stopping in between 0-1 also. How to achieve this. I don't want to stop my slider pointer in-between my range values.

Please guide me the best approach for the above scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083375/ios-how-to-make-slider-stop-at-discrete-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you handle the value changed callback from the slider, modify the value. Something like:

```
slider.value = roundf(slider.value);
```

Comment: i used the below code and it worked great. // float roundedValue = roundf(sliderName.value / 1.0f) * 1.0f;    
    [sliderName setValue:roundedValue];